# Is there a way to remove or edit the word "Caption" in a Tableau caption?

Tags: tableau-api

It's pretty simple -- I just want to hide or replace the "Caption" title in a Tableau worksheet.

I'm using it for footnotes, more or less, so "Caption" at the top of this section is not what I want the users to see. I've tried searching all the Tableau and external documentation.

Comment: Pls give a screenshot as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's talking about **Worksheet**>**Caption** and the box that shows up at the bottom of the view has a "Caption" title/header.

I don't think this can be changed right now, but you can probably use the text object on a dashboard in lieu of the caption feature in a worksheet. It'd likely take up the same amount of screen real estate in the end

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. Yes, I've used text objects and rollover icons on dashboards for this. It'd be nice not to have to create a dashboard.